# May there be any cases where collective adjectives are allowed to be used without the preceding definite article?

Tags: grammar, definite-article

One of Truman Capote's short stories, [The Thanksgiving Visitor](http://shortstorymasterpieces.altervista.org/capotethanksgivingvisitor.html), starts with "Talk about mean! Odd Henderson was the meanest human creature in my experience. "

I take it that the "mean" in the exclamatory sentence is a collective adjective referring to a group of mean people, but shouldn't collective adjectives be *always* preceded by "the"? If yes, what could be the reason for the author's omitting it? If no, what may be the cases when "the" could be omitted before a collective adjective?

Comment: "Talk about fast! I was in and out of the dentist's chair in under 10 minutes."  A colloquial construction, roughly in the same register as "Believe you me".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Talk about mean!

In this case, *mean* is not what you call a 'collective adjective'—that is, an adjective employed as a noun designating the entire set of entities which can be characterized as 'mean'.

It should be understood as a mention of the word *mean* employed as a topic of discourse. You may paraphrase:

> Let me give you a definitive example of appropriate use of the word *mean*!

Answer (score 0):

"Talk about" here could be paraphrased as "how" (in the exclamatory rather than interrogative usage of that word).

"How mean!" or "how mean he is!" would have a similar meaning.

(When followed by a noun, it might be paraphrased as "what".)

Definitions are here (though they do little to elucidate the grammar):

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/talk-about-something

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/talk_about_%25E2%2580%2594!